# merge/combine two FFMPEG commands together into one command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, merge

I have been processing videos for a while and I have been using ffmpeg to make my life easy. But there are two commands which I want to combine into single command:-

Step 1:- Divide a video vertically into two parts and then stack them horizontally

`ffmpeg -i usa.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw:ih/2:0:0[top];[0]crop=iw:ih/2:0:oh[bottom];[top][bottom]hstack" -preset fast -c:a copy usa$.mp4`

Step 2:- Combine 3 videos into single video (the video from Step 1 will be in between the start.mp4 and end.mp4)

`ffmpeg -i start.mp4 -i usa$.mp4 -i end.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" usa_.mp4`

Can anyone please combine the videos into single command.I will be then able to save a lot of computing time(I guess that)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First perform the crop and stacking, then send its result to concat.

`ffmpeg -i start.mp4 -i usa.mp4 -i end.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex "[1]crop=iw:ih/2:0:0[top];[1]crop=iw:ih/2:0:oh[bottom];[top][bottom]hstack[vs];[0:v] [0:a] [vs] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" usa_.mp4`